# ICommand for Button Press AND Release in an MVVM style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am quite happily using an `ICommand` implementation to handle a single action on a button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ActionDown}">Press Me</Button>
```

With the `ICommand` being implemented via a `RelayCommand`

But what I have not been able to find is a simple way to supply an action for both the press **and** the release actions (both on SO and elsewhere on the interwebs).  IE I want to do something *like* this, but I have no idea how to do it:

```
<Button PressCommand="{Binding Path=ActionDown}" ReleaseCommand="{Binding Path=ActionUp}">Press and Release Me</Button>
```

What is the correct MVVM way to handle such a requirement?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EventTrigger` from `System.Windows.Interactivity` to trigger command on event

```
<Button Content="Press Me">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ActionDown}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ActionUp}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

you'll need to add reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and define namespace

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Comment: Thanks for that,but how would you wrap that into a re-usable component?  It's fine for a one off button, but I need to stamp out about 20 such buttons so I am also looking for ways to minimize cut and past.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create your own class extending from `Button` , defining bindable commands for MouseDown and MouseUp.

Example:

```
public class PressAndReleaseButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PressCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(PressAndReleaseButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// The Press command to bind
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand PressCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PressCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReleaseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ReleaseCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(PressAndReleaseButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// The Release command to bind
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand ReleaseCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ReleaseCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReleaseCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor registers mouse down and up events to fire commands
    /// </summary>
    public PressAndReleaseButton()
    {
        MouseDown += (o, a) => 
                 {
                     if (PressCommand.CanExecute(null)) PressCommand.Execute(null);
                 }
        MouseUp += (o, a) => 
                 {
                     if (ReleaseCommand.CanExecute(null)) ReleaseCommand.Execute(null);
                 } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going, but isn't this then going to bypass the `CanExecute` part of the `RelayCommand`?

Comment: Oops, I kinda went a bit too fast in this. You can just call `CanExecute` yourself, let me update the event handlers

Comment: Done. In this case I assumed there is no argument (thus `null` in Execute's argument), but you can of course use any/bind them if needed (create `PressCommandParameter` dependency property for example)

Comment: Aside from the missing commas on the `MouseUp/MouseDown +=`, user controls don't respond to `MouseUp/MouseDown`.  However they do respond to `PreviewMouseUp/PreviewMouseDown`